# Python find subsets of a list of lists that fulfil a specific condition

Tags: python, list, subset, criteria

thanks for giving me the opportunity to ask a question here.

A small backstory: I need / want to find sets that fulfil certain conditions. These conditions can be quite complex, but I'll hopefully be able to adapt based on an easy example.

First, let's create an example:

```
from itertools import permutations
perm3 = list(permutations([1,2,3,4],3))
```

We create all permutations of length 3 from these numbers (e.g. (1,2,3),(1,3,2),...). Now, I would like to find all subsets that fulfil a specific condition. For example, find the subset of all permutations that have "3" never in the first place. That alone should be possible quite easily:

```
first_neq_3 = [tuple for tuple in perm3 if tuple[0]!= 3]
```

But, obviously that only gives me one subset - namely the "biggest" one. Now, I would like to find ALL subsets that fulfil this condition. A short example, let's say first_neq_3 = [(1,2,3),(2,1,3),(1,3,2),(2,3,1)] - then I would also like to find [(1,2,3),(2,1,3)] and so on.
I admit, it's a pretty simple problem for the example provided, but I am stuck and it gets more complicated with more complex conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need all the subsets of the list `first_neq_3` above (of all possible lengths). Then you can get them using the code below

```
from itertools import combinations
sum(map(lambda r: list(combinations(first_neq_3, r)), range(1, len(first_neq_3)+1)), [])
```

**EXPLANATION**

The key here is the `map` function. The `itertools.combinations` gives you all the subsets of a `list` of a given length. Since we need the subsets of all lengths we perform that action using `r` as a dummy variable running over all possible lenghts. Since the first argument of the `map` must be a function is is handy to use a `lambda` expression.

Comment: You do understand me correctly. And yes, that function does exactly what I want it to do!
I was just wondering, if you knew a good link to learn about Lambda functions, and if you have an explanation as to why you knew / thought of using it in this situation? Experience I guess?

Comment: I added some more explanation to my answer